# Is it possible to send a Twilio SMS with my cell phone number as the From?

Tags: twilio

I have searched on Twilio support and on StackOverflow but I can't seem to find a clear answer to this so hoping someone from the community can educate me.

Is it possible to send text messages from a non-Twilio cell phone number that I own?  The Twilio console won't let me Host the number and I'm not sure Porting the number is the right way to go either.

I send out monthly text updates to my customers (right now, a lot of copying and pasting) from my Verizon  cell phone and I'm curious if there's a way I can programmatically do it using my cell phone number as the From?  My customers and I are all in the US.  The goal is that when they reply, I can engage in a cell-to-cell text conversation outside of Twilio.  Is this possible?

I know I can always send from a Twilio number and then have the responses forwarded to my cell phone but if there's a way to send directly from my Verizon cell phone number, that would be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send an SMS from a non-Twilio number nor can you host (vs port) a mobile number on any CPaaS providers platform.

What are you copy/pasting content from you cell phone to create a monthly newsletter? There has to be a more elegant way to assemble the information and then send it out via SMS from the Twilio number.

[A Hacker Got All My Texts for $16](https://www.vice.com/en/article/y3g8wb/hacker-got-my-texts-16-dollars-sakari-netnumber)

Comment: Thank you @Alan, that makes sense and interesting article as well.  To solve my problem I will start sending texts programmatically from a Twilio number and then have any responses forwarded to my cell phone so I can continue the conversation that way.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing. There is a blog that may be of interest here, SMS Forwarding and Responding Using Twilio and JavaScript - https://www.twilio.com/blog/sms-forwarding-and-responding-using-twilio-and-javascript.